# Java IRC bot commands

Tags: java, irc, bots

So I'm trying to make an IRC bot in java, I am currently using the pircbot api.
what i want is to be able to do a command like:
    !dl.exec (url of file)
or 
    !update (url of file)
which would be the same as the first, but kills itself after execution.

when i try

```
if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("!dl.exec" +paramString1)){
}
```

it tells me
    "cannot find symbol variable paramString1"

Comment: Looks like you don't have a variable called `paramString1` - can you show us more code for context?

Comment: Post more code - where do you declare `paramString1`? Why do you expect it to exist here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out you can also do:

```
if (message.toLowerCase().startsWith("!dl.exec.jar")){
    String[] args = message.split(" ");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
if(message.toLowerCase().startsWith("!dl.exec"))
{
    String param = message.substring("!dl.exec".length() + 1);
}
```

This will check if the `message` starts with the command you are looking for. `param` is the substring of `message` that will contain the url

Comment: Good interpretation of a vague question! I think this is what the OP meant.